# Is there any ways we can create subset data from S/4HANA

Tags: s4hana

Need to find out a way to subset data from S/4HANA

I know we have TDMS which can be used with SAP ECC to extract subset of actual data. So need similar kind of way or tool or third-party tool which does it.